# How do I download my IoT certificate created via CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, aws-cloudformation, aws-iot

I'm using AWS CloudFormation to create an IoT `Thing`, `Policy` and `Certificate`. My stack creates successfully, however, I can't access the certificate file that CloudFormation creates.

Looking at the aws docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iot-certificate.html#d0e83089) the only output you can get from the certificate via CloudFormation is the `ARN` and the `Certificate ID`. However, there is no way to retrieve your certificate using the `ARN` or `Certificate ID` that I can see.

If you upload your certificate signing request (CSR) via the AWS IoT Console, it displays a download link that you can get your certificate file.

[image]

Unfortunately I need to use CloudFormation to create the IoT `Certificate`. However it looks like you can download the certificate after it's been created. Specifically it states:

> Certificates can be retrieved at any time

I have been unsuccessfully scouring the docs and web interface to figure out how I can download my certificate "at any time". I'm relatively new to the whole world of certs and private keys so hopefully I missed something easy.

Does anyone know if it is possible to get your certificate from an IoT `Certificate` created by CloudFormation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certificates created using CloudFormation (Via a CSR) can be retrieved via the following ways

**Aws IoT webpage**

Just navigate to Security - Certificates, click on `...` and select Download.

[image]

**AWS CLI**

As you mention the CLI is also an option

```
aws iot describe-certificate --certificate-id fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd3
```

Will return

```
{
    "certificateDescription": {
        "certificateArn": "arn:aws:iot:eu-central-1:xxxxxx", 
        "status": "ACTIVE", 
        "certificateId": "fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd3", 
        "lastModifiedDate": 1519840881.49, 
        "certificatePem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDsTCCApmg.....VsAzFQ==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n", 
        "transferData": {}, 
        "ownedBy": "123456789", 
        "creationDate": 1519840820.888
    }
```

**Amazon IoT SDK**

Can also be used to retrieve the certificate content (PEM format) as a String based on a certificate ID (that you can output via cloudformation)

```
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.AWSIot;
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.AWSIotClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.DescribeCertificateRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.DescribeCertificateResult;

DescribeCertificateRequest describeCertificateRequest = new DescribeCertificateRequest();
describeCertificateRequest.setCertificateId("fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd371fcd3");
DescribeCertificateResult describeCertificateResult = awsIot.describeCertificate(describeCertificateRequest);
describeCertificateResult.getCertificateDescription().getCertificatePem();
```

AFAIK it is not possible to output it as a variable within a cloudformation template.

Answer (score 1):

Ah I found a way using the AWS CLI. But there really needs to be a way to get it via CloudFormation :(

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iot/describe-certificate.html

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to do this in CDK, this works for me, however, I cannot write the output to a local file:

```
    const iotCertificate = new iot.CfnCertificate(this, "iot-certificate", {
      status: "ACTIVE",
      certificateSigningRequest: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./credentials/cert.req"), "utf8"),
    });

    const describeIotCertificate = new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, 'describe-iot-certificate', {
      onCreate: {
        service: 'Iot',
        action: 'describeCertificate',
        parameters: {
          certificateId: `${iotCertificate.attrId}`
        },
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
      },
      onUpdate: {
        service: 'Iot',
        action: 'describeCertificate',
        parameters: {
          certificateId: `${iotCertificate.attrId}`
        },
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(Date.now().toString()),
      },
      policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({
        resources: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE,
      }),
    });
    describeIotCertificate.node.addDependency(iotCertificate);

    const iotCertificatePem = describeIotCertificate.getResponseField('certificateDescription.certificatePem');
    new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'IoT certificate PEM', { value: iotCertificatePem });
```